# Why is .toUpperCase() not wanting to work in a multi-prompt command?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm having an issue where `message.channel.toUpperCase()` on line 81 (probably applies to lines 96, 108, 135, 150, and 162) doesn't want to read `channel`. I want to make a command that follows several prompts to gather information. It starts with asking for a team ID. Depending on which of two teams that team ID could match, it enters another prompt for whether a match was a win or loss.

I haven't coded in the SQL queries to update the database as needed because I've gotten stuck here. Not too sure what to do about this.

I've included a Pastebin if that makes things easier to look at.

Thanks in advance.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/CJ4YAvXS

```
const Command = require('../Command.js');
const { MessageEmbed, MessageAttachment, PermissionOverwrites } = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const { pong } = require('../../utils/emojis.json')

module.exports = class MyCommandName extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'reportmatch',
      aliases: ['reportm'],
      usage: 'reportmatch <match ID>',
      description: 'Initializes a report for Wins and Losses',
      // userPermissions: [''],
      ownerOnly: false,
      type: client.types.QUEUE
    });
}
  async run(message, args) 
  {


    /** ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * CONNECT TO SQL DATABASE
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */ 
     const pool = mysql.createPool(
      {
        host: `localhost`,
        user: process.env.sqluser,
        password: process.env.sqlpass,
        database: `performancetracker`,
        waitForConnections: true,
        connectionLimit: 30,
        queueLimit: 0
      }
    );
    
    pool.on("acquire", function (connection) {
      console.log("[SQL] [STATUS] Connection %d acquired", connection.threadId);
    });
    
    pool.on("release", function (connection) {
      console.log("[SQL] [STATUS] Connection %d released", connection.threadId);
    });
    pool.on("enqueue", function (e) {
      console.log("[SQL] [STATUS] Waiting for available connection slot...",e);
    });
        
     const match = (args[0])

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //  SEND QUERY TO DATABASE TO GATHER RELEVANT INFO   //
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     const [team1, team1d, team1e] = await pool.query("select Team1 from `performancetracker`.`matches` where MatchID=?", [match]);
     const [team2, team2d, team2e] = await pool.query("select Team2 from `performancetracker`.`matches` where MatchID=?", [match]);

     const [team1id, playeridd, playeride] = await pool.query("select ID from `performancetracker`.`teams` where TeamName=?", [team1 [0].Team1]);
     const [team2id, plaearidd, palayride] = await pool.query("select ID from `performancetracker`.`teams` where TeamName=?", [team2 [0].Team2]);

     console.log(`|${team1 [0].Team1}|`)
     console.log(`|${team1id [0].ID}|`)
     
            // ASK FOR TEAM ID

     const embed = new MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`Please enter your Team ID`)

 let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
message.channel.send(embed)
 await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
max: 1,
time: 30000,
errors: ['You didn\'t provide a valid Team ID.  Please try this command again.']
})
.then(message => {

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // IF TEAM ID MATCHES TEAM 1 THEN ASK FOR WIN OR LOSS//
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${team1id [0].ID}`) {
        const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Please enter your match result (W/L)`)
        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
    message.channel.send(embed1)
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['You didn\'t provide a valid response. Please try this command again.']
    })
    .then(message => {
    message = message.first()

            // IF THE RESPONSE IS A WIN RECORD AS WIN

    if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `W`) {
        const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Win Reported")
            .setDescription(`You have reported the result for ${team1 [0].Team1}. If this was a mistake, please run this command again.`)
            .addField('Team Name:', `${team1 [0].Team1}`, true)
            .addField('Match Result', `Win`, true)
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(embed2)

            // IF THE RESPONSE IS A LOSS RECORD AS LOSS

    } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `L`) {
            const embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Win Reported")
                .setDescription(`You have reported the result for ${team1 [0].Team1}. If this was a mistake, please run this command again.`)
                .addField('Team Name:', `${team1 [0].Team1}`, true)
                .addField('Match Result', `Win`, true)
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed3)
        
            // IF NEITHER WIN OR LOSS IS PROVIDED THEN SAY THAT ONE IS NEEDED

    } else {
            const embed4 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("No Report")
                .setDescription(`You have incorrectly reported a win or loss. Make sure your response is in caps. Please try this command again.`)
                .addField('Team Name:', `${team1 [0].Team1}`, true)
                .addField('Match Result', `Unreported`, true)
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed4)
}})

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // IF TEAM ID MATCHES TEAM 2 THEN ASK FOR WIN OR LOSS //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `${team2id [0].ID}`) {
            const embed5 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Please enter your match result (Win/Loss)`)
            let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
        message.channel.send(embed5)
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ['You didn\'t provide a valid response. Please try this command again.']
        })
        .then(message => {
        message = message.first()
    
                // IF THE RESPONSE IS A WIN RECORD AS WIN
    
        if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `W`) {
            const embed6 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Win Reported")
                .setDescription(`You have reported the result for ${team2 [0].Team2}. If this was a mistake, please run this command again.`)
                .addField('Team Name:', `${team2 [0].Team2}`, true)
                .addField('Match Result', `Win`, true)
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(embed6)
    
                // IF THE RESPONSE IS A LOSS RECORD AS LOSS
    
        } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == `L`) {
                const embed7 = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Win Reported")
                    .setDescription(`You have reported the result for ${team2 [0].Team2}. If this was a mistake, please run this command again.`)
                    .addField('Team Name:', `${team2 [0].Team2}`, true)
                    .addField('Match Result', `Win`, true)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setTimestamp()
                message.channel.send(embed7)
            
                // IF NEITHER WIN OR LOSS IS PROVIDED THEN SAY THAT ONE IS NEEDED
    
        } else {
                const embed8 = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("No Report")
                    .setDescription(`You have incorrectly reported a win or loss. Please try this command again.`)
                    .addField('Team Name:', `${team2 [0].Team2}`, true)
                    .addField('Match Result', `Unreported`, true)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setTimestamp()
                message.channel.send(embed8)
    }})

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // IF TEAM ID DOES NOT MATCH ANY TEAMS FOR THAT MATCH //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                } else {
                        const embed9 = new MessageEmbed()
                            .setTitle("No Team Found")
                            .setDescription(`The Team ID you have given isn't recognized for teams in this match. Please try this command again.`)
                            .addField('Team Name:', `Unknown`, true)
                            .setTimestamp()
                        message.channel.send(embed9)
                }
})}}
```

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: For this project I'm using 12.3.1 since I have no desire for slash commands on a bot that'll be inside one single server.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` key needs to be a parameter of your `collector` as well, otherwise it won't work.

Change:

```
await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
max: 1,
time: 30000,
errors: ['You didn\'t provide a valid Team ID.  Please try this command again.']
})
```

To:

```
await message.channel.awaitMessages({
filter,
max: 1,
time: 30000,
errors: ['You didn\'t provide a valid Team ID.  Please try this command again.']
})
```

Comment: Doing that seems to cause an error as well. I've actually never seen this particular error before.
.
Function.prototype.apply was called on #<Object>, which is a object and not a function

Comment: This doesn't seem to effect another command I have where there is only one instance of response.

Comment: You mentioned using discord.js v12.3.1, there have been changes that include the collector. I'm afraid I cannot help you with this.
I recommend you update to the latest version and modify your code accordingly.
Since you plan to only use the bot in one server, you do not have to worry about needing to implement slash commands. That is only necessary for verified bots.